# WKWebView makes a black screen when the app was in the background

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, wkwebview

I recently changed from UIWebView to WKWebView in Xcode and so far everything is fine.
But when I use the "Link Preview" (a feature that is very usefull for me) check mark field in the IBs Attribute Inspector, the App comes back completely black when it was in the background.
That means that the user has to kill it, when he wants to use it again.

Here is the Code for the WebViewController:

```
@interface WebViewController ()

@end

@implementation WebViewController
@synthesize activityIndicatorView = _activityIndicatorView;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        NSLog(@"Webview");
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _webView.UIDelegate = self;
    _webView.navigationDelegate = self;


    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.webLink]]];


    [self setupConstraints];

}


-(void)setupConstraints {
    [self.webView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.webView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.webView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.webView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.webView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
}


@end
```

and this is how I call the WKWebViewController from a tableView:

```
 WebViewController *webVC = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:nil];

                        webVC.webLink = str;

                        [self.navigationController pushViewController:webVC animated:YES];
```

how can I prevent the Controller to be black, when 
"Link Preview" is on AND the app comes back after it was in background?

(Xcode 11.4.1, Target iOS 11)

Thank you very much!
Martin

Comment: Have you tried to reload your `WKWebView` on event like applicationWill/DidBecomeActive ?  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622956-applicationdidbecomeactive

Comment: Thank you.
I have discovered a mistake in the MainWindows.xib: 
I had a Window with this attributes in the Size Inspector: Layout was "Automatic" - now I use "Translates Mask Into Constraints" --- and everything is ok.